# Reduce time to check jquery cometd meta connect?

Tags: jquery, websocket, cometd

How can we reduce the time to fire meta/connect listeners in jquery cometd? I have a scenario when the signal strength is low, I want to display a message. But in cometd the connection is hanged before going to disconnect state. I referred the documentation but couldn't find a good solution.

Comment: You need to be a lot clearer than this question. "connection is hanged" is too vague - could be a normal behavior when doing long polling; furthermore you don't specify what transport you use, you don't specify what client you use, you don't attach any log that show the problem, etc.

Comment: Hi Simone, sorry for the confusion. What I wanted to do is simply displaying a message when the data connection is too weak and taking time to fetch data. I see the connect is polled each time but I wanted to increase the rate of meta connect handler so that I can use it to check when it is too long. But I couldn't find that and I thought of implementing a heartbeat channel to poll the connection. Is that a good approach according to your framework? Bdw appreciate your community contribution very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CometD client application can detect if the connectivity with the server is broken by registering a listener on the `/meta/connect` channel:

```js
cometd.addListener('/meta/connect', function(m) {
    connectionBroken = !m.successful;
});
```

CometD works in a way that a `/meta/connect` message is sent with a period determined by the server `timeout` configuration parameter, by default 30 seconds. The server "holds" the reply, and only replies to this message as soon as it has a broadcast message to deliver back to the client, or after the `timeout` elapsed.

What described above is the "heart-beat" mechanism implemented by CometD, and there is no need for applications to re-implement another heart-beat mechanism - it will not be any more efficient than CometD's.

If the TCP connection is closed (by the client, by the server, or by an intermediary) while the reply is being "held" by the server, the client should immediately detect it (this depends on the client implementation - browsers may delay this notification), and CometD will notify the listener above.

If the TCP connection is zombie, that is packets are dropped, there is no TCP notification that the connection has been closed, etc. then CometD waits at most `timeout` + `maxNetworkDelay` (see https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_javascript_configure), then CometD will notify the listener above.

If your application publishes messages while the connection is zombie, CometD waits at most `maxNetworkDelay`, then fails the message callback (see https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_javascript_publish).

Unfortunately, zombie connections are a real pain to detect; with some careful coding, however, CometD allows you to detect them within `maxNetworkDelay`, more or less, with a mixed usage of a `/meta/connect` listener and message callbacks.

Be careful that a too small `maxNetworkDelay` can cause a lot of false detections for broken connections.

To sum up, precise coding using a `/meta/connect` listener and message callbacks, paired with tuning of `maxNetworkDelay` should give applications the ability to detect connectivity problems as fast as possible without (too many) false reports.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the detailed answer. I think this scenario will solve it. One thing, is there anyway to configure this timeout in the server side without changing it in the imported java-cometd library?

Comment: The parameter `timeout` is configured on the server, the parameter `maxNetworkDelay` is configured on the client.